# zoho server images not loading in react native

Tags: react-native, image, webview, zoho

I have zoho image url like this -

```
https://crm.zoho.in/crm/org60011678237/specific/ViewAttachment?fileId=64i8a0191a1c3019d4a9e89fcecfc367b61dc&module=Accounts&parentId=251496000005863051&creatorId=251496000000244001&id=251496000005863052&name=reportImage%270.41817424824663885%27.jpg&downLoadMode=default
```

and I am showing this url like this

```
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <WebView
            source={{
              html: `
              <html>
              <body><img src="https://crm.zoho.in/crm/org60011678237/specific/ViewAttachment?fileId=64i8a0191a1c3019d4a9e89fcecfc367b61dc&module=Accounts&parentId=251496000005863051&creatorId=251496000000244001&id=251496000005863052&name=reportImage%270.41817424824663885%27.jpg&downLoadMode=default">
                </body></html>`,

              // uri: "https://crm.zoho.in/crm/org60011678237/ViewImage?fileId=64i8a0191a1c3019d4a9e89fcecfc367b61dc&module=Accounts&parentId=251496000005863051&creatorId=251496000000244001&id=251496000005863052&name=reportImage%270.41817424824663885%27.jpg&downLoadMode=inline",
            }}
            javaScriptEnabled
            domStorageEnabled
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs
            startInLoadingState
            originWhitelist={["*"]}
            mixedContentMode="compatibility"
          />
          {/* <Image
            source={{ uri: selectedImage }}
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "50%",
              resizeMode: "contain",
            }}
          /> */}
        </View>
```

but image not loading or sometime opening zoho web page please guide me over this. thanks

Comment: Does the image display if you put its url directly in the browser?